# XML parsing error: <unknown>:4:0: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: xml, itunes, feed

I have absolutely no idea why this is returning an error all of a sudden.

XML parsing error:

> `<unknown>`:4:0: not well-formed (invalid token)

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" version="2.0"
<channel>
<title>The Deep(ish) Thoughts Podcast</title>
<link>http://www.deepishthoughts.com</link>
<language>en-us</language>
<copyright>2017</copyright>
<description> The Deep(ish) Thoughts Podcast </description>
<itunes:subtitle>Sports talk with Chris Horwedel and Anshu Khanna of DeepishThoughts.com</itunes:subtitle>
<itunes:author>Deep(ish) Thoughts</itunes:author>
<itunes:summary>Chris Horwedel and Anshu Khanna of Deep(ish) Thoughts talk about the biggest sports stories of the week.</itunes:summary>
<itunes:keywords> NFL, NBA, Sports, College Football, MLB, NHL, News, My Block Radio, Horwedel, Glymph </itunes:keywords>
<itunes:owner>
<itunes:name>Chris Horwedel</itunes:name>
<itunes:email>Hordel44@aol.com</itunes:email>
</itunes:owner>
<itunes:image href="http://www.archive.org/download/DTPitunes/DTPitunes.png"/>
<itunes:category text="Sports & Recreation"/>
<itunes:category text="Professional"/>
</itunes:category>
```

Comment: If you don't show us the XML _in the question_ (a link is not acceptable) we cannot help you.

Comment: Jim Garrison is absolutely correct.  Next time, make your question stand on its own without dependence on an off-site resource.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML has several mistakes preventing it from being well-formed:

1. The opening `rss` tag is missing a `>`.
2. There is an unescaped `&` in `Sports & Recreation`.
3. There is an extraneous close `</itunes:category>` tag.